# Python requests, how to know what format data is in?

Tags: python, python-requests

How do i find out what format the data i am trying to request is in?

The data can be found in the following address: https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response headers for this request include

```
content-type: application/json
```

as your browser will tell you. So it is [JSON](https://json.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Type` header field in the response is what you're looking for.